# When is there an inclusion between regular Orlicz Spaces?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, orlicz-spaces

It is a classical result that $L^p(\Omega) \subset L^q(\Omega)$ when $q<p$ and $|\Omega| < \infty$. I'd like to know if there is an Orlicz version of this fact. In other words, let $L^{G_1}$ and $L^{G_2}$ be Orlicz spaces. When do we have $L^{G_1} \subset L^{G_2}$?

It seems that this result holds only (maybe) if the Orlicz spaces $L^{G_1} \subset L^{G_2}$ are regular, that is, satisfy the famous $\Delta_2$ and $\nabla_2$ conditions. That is,
let's assume the conditions for N-functions introduced by G. Lieberman (see \cite{Lieberman}). More precisely,
$$
G'(t) = g(t), \ \ \text{with} \ \ g \in C^{0}([0,+ \infty]) \cap C^{1}((0,+ \infty])
$$
and for $1< g_{0} \le g_{1} $ fixed constants
$$
0 < g_0 \le \frac{t g'(t)}{g(t)} \le g_1,\quad\forall t > 0.
$$

If you want to know more about Orlicz Spaces any book about Orlicz Spaces has the concept or articles, for instance see the beginning of [Martinez and Wolanski - A minimum problem with free boundary in Orlicz spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602388).

More specifically, let $G^p$ and $G^q$ be regular N-functions with
$$
0<g_0^p \le  \frac{t(g_p)'(t)}{g_p(t)} \le g_1^p < \infty
$$
and
$$
0<g_0^q \le  \frac{t(g_q)'(t)}{g_q(t)} \le g_1^q < \infty.
$$
Is there a relation between $g_0^p$, $g_1^p$, $g_0^q$, and $g_1^q$ which implies inclusion between $L^{G^p}$ and $L^{G^q}$?

**Obs 1** Notice that $p$ and $q$ above are indices not powers.
**Obs 2** I asked this in [Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4687898/when-there-is-inclusion-of-orlicz-spaces) without answer even when I offered 250 in bounty. I believe now that here is the right place to ask. Any help is welcome, reference, direct proof etc.

**Is this correct?**

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{tg'(t)}{g(t)} \le g_1 \Rightarrow \frac{g'(t)}{g(t)} \le \frac{g_1}{t}
\end{eqnarray}
As $g:R^+ \longrightarrow R^+$ saisfy $g(t)>0$ and is a $C^{1}(0,\infty) $ nondecreasing, we have $g'(t) \ge 0$ and integrating, we obtain
\begin{eqnarray}
ln(g(t)) \le ln( t^{g_1}) \Rightarrow g(t) \le t^{g_1}
\end{eqnarray}
Analogouslly, we get $ g^q(t) \le t^{g_1^q}$ and $t^{g_0^{p}} \le g_p(t) $. Observing that

1. $t^{g_1^q} \le t^{g_0^{p}}$ for $t>1 $ if $g_1^q \le g_0^{p}$. In this case $ g_q(t) \le g_p(t) $
2. Orlicz class are equal Orlicz Spaces if and only if the $N$-function $G \in \Delta_2$
3. The Orlicz classes $L^{G^p}$ and $L^{G^q}$ given respectivally by the N-functions $G^p$ and $G^q$ satisfy $L^{G^p} \subset L^{G^q} $ if and only if there is constantes $a,b$ so that
   $$
   G^q(t) \le aG^p(t) \quad \mbox{for all} \quad t\ge b.
   $$
   we conclude that $L^{G^p} \subset L^{G^q} $ if $g_1^q \le g_0^{p}$

**Obs1** I do not know if does hold the reciproc (this is less important for me)
**Obs2** I do not know much about Orlicz Spaces, so it is possíble that it is a classical result that can be found or deduced in books. Because of this I need a proof verification

Comment: This is not the paper cited but a equivalente one.

Comment: I'm still working in this paper. I mean that the concept that i take a picture is the same in the Wolansk's paper.

Comment: I edited the question as you observed

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446285/when-is-there-an-inclusion-between-regular-orlicz-spaces#comment1152783_446285), thanks!  You removed the equation which seemed to be the key point, so I restored it.  You left the misspelling "Lierbaman", but, based on your `\cite{Lieberman}`, you meant "Lieberman", so I corrected that too.  Now what is the reference `Lieberman`?

Comment: Lieberman, Gary M. The natural generalization of the natural conditions of Ladyzhensaya and Uralt-
seva for elliptic equations. Comm. in partial differential equations. 16 (1991),(2-3), 311–361.

Comment: Answer posted to the math.se question.

Comment: Ok math extack exchenge